# Stored Procedures access when no access in a table

Tags: sql-server, security, stored-procedures, data-access-layer

All,

In SQL Server, can a stored procedure (beeing ran from a user) write to table where the user doesn't have access to write directly to the table?

Rgds,

MK

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct answer is **NO**, a stored procedure does not have access to write into a table. However most users perceive it, incorrectly, as YES because of [Ownership Chains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx):

> When multiple database objects access
>   each other sequentially, the sequence
>   is known as a chain. Although such
>   chains do not independently exist,
>   when SQL Server traverses the links in
>   a chain, SQL Server evaluates
>   permissions on the constituent objects
>   differently than it would if it were
>   accessing the objects separately.
>   These differences have important
>   implications for managing security.
>   Ownership chaining enables managing
>   access to multiple objects, such as
>   multiple tables, by setting
>   permissions on one object, such as a
>   view.

So a procedure will be able to write into a table that the user has no permissions to write into *if they form an ownership chain*. This means that if the owner of the schema that contains the table is the same as the owner of the schema that contains the procedure, an ownership chain is formed and the procedure is allowed to write into the table. Since the vast majority of objects deployed in practice belong to the `dbo` schema, an ownership chain is almost always formed.

It is important to comprehend these details, so you can troubleshoot problems and understand *why* is the procedure allowed to write into the table. Erland Sommarskog has an excellent comprehensive write up on this topic: [Giving Permissions through Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html). This article goes into great detail explaining all the options available. Your best option, far better than ownership chaining, is [code signing](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates).

Understanding how this works also helps understanding why dynamic SQL seems to 'break': running dynamic SQL is an automatic break in the ownership chain, which causes all 'magic' to disappear. And it also helps understand why this 'magic' appears not to work outside the database: [cross db ownership chaining Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188694.aspx) default value is 0.

Comment: cannot upvote this enough!  just tested this out and it's true.  now i have to change the ownership on some of my schemas....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the user is GRANTed EXEC permissions on the SP, any actions it takes (within that database) are allowed.

Going over to another database will require permissions on the underlying user to be examined.

Also, dynamic SQL built within the SP will require the underlying user to have permissions.

Comment: The exception is if you use dynamic SQL in the proc. Then the rights must be at the table or view level.

Comment: @HLGEM - Yes, that's also true, dynamic SQL will be executing in the context of the calling user

Comment: @Remus Sorry - you are absolutely right.  In the case where all the objects are not owned by dbo, it is not this simple.

Comment: i'm glad i read this post, because i was under the impression that anyone with exec permissions on one schema couldn't do anything in my other schema, but that was only half-true, the schemas need to have different owners for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

The main restriction in play in this scenario is whether the user can execute the stored procedure.

When *creating* the stored procedure, it needs to be done with a login/user that has the necessary write access to the table in question.